# wireguard handshake did not complete

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, wireguard

У меня есть сервер Ubuntu на AWS. Я пытаюсь запустить на нём WireGuard VPN, но мне выбивает ошибку в заголовке:

```
2021-11-20 01:04:44.886: [TUN] [test1] Handshake for peer 1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5505) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2021-11-20 01:04:44.887: [TUN] [test1] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5505)
2021-11-20 01:04:49.949: [TUN] [test1] Handshake for peer 1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5505) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
2021-11-20 01:04:49.949: [TUN] [test1] Sending handshake initiation to peer 1 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5505)
```

На сервере при команде `wg show` есть строка:

```
transfer: 740 B received, 15.48 KiB sent
```

Я скидывал пир знакомому не из моей страны (я сам из Туркменистана), у него всё отлично работает. К томе же, и у меня на андроиде работал VPN, а на следующий день - перестал.

Мой конфиг сервера:

```
[Interface]
MTU = 1412
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
Address = 10.7.0.1/24
PrivateKey = UJ+PrVmiOsUzep2Z6wqoJ/Cd9OniqWu3JlMWnEuAEGI=
ListenPort = 5505

# BEGIN_PEER test1
[Peer]
PublicKey = gG/ng6Umfghsbhg6bn5ypNiu0ntlZUWkF4IkMmlNCC0=
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.2/32
# END_PEER test1
```

`PostUp` и `PostDown` я решил лишь опробовать, в надежде, что после этого что то заработает. UFW на сервере не активен, а в security groups на AWS стоит значение `ALL TRAFICC`.

Расскоментированные и добавленные строки в файле **/etc/sysctl.conf**:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.wg0.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Я уже несколько дней ищу в гугле ответ, но всё безуспешно. Буду очень рад любой помощи.
P.S.пробовал несколько портов: 443, 52180, 56137 - не помогло.

Comment: Попробуй сменить порт (рандомный, а не понравившийся) и использовать PresharedKey. Сгенерируй конфиги заново, например через https://www.wireguardconfig.com/

Comment: @ГеннадийП порты я использовал разные, он вечер проработал на 5505, на следующий день перестал.(работал только на андроиде)

на счёт PresharedKey, он есть, но я убрал его лишь при написании вопроса.
и кстати, я использовал скрипт для генерации впн'а и создания новых клиентов. [ссылка на скрипт](https://github.com/Nyr/wireguard-install).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в вашем сервере, а в самом Туркменистане. WireGuard имеет специфический тип пакетов и очень легко палится, поэтому он точно не вариант. Поищите в интернете варианты, как замаскироваться под обычный https-трафик, может помочь. Но вообще, главное правило VPN в Туркменистане - не палиться, а для этого надо использовать как можно сильнее замаскированные протоколы и ни в коем случае не наглеть, пользоваться крайне аккуратно, не привлекая внимание гигабайтами шифрованного трафика на иностранные адреса. Про YouTube лучше забыть, максимум новости почитать.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]